# Play audio file from a commands in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I want to play an **audio file** in my folder from a command on Discord bot, in **Discord.js**. How should i do? Thanks
This is my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client =  new Discord.Client();
var ChannelId = "ID_CHANNEL";
var token = "TOKEN";

client.on("message", (message) => {

  if(message.content == "!audio"){
    /*HERE*/
  }
  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to find a voice channel first, for example the one the user typing the command is in (if any) like this :

```
const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send("No voice channel.");
```

Then join the channel and then play your file :

```
voiceChannel.join()
   .then(connection => {
      connection.play('/path/to/yourFile.mp3');
   });
```

You can check what else you can do by reading [the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceConnection?scrollTo=play).